# Minimizar google maps

Tags: google-maps, url

estoy empezando a utilizar tasker y he creado un código que al decir el destino al que quiero ir, comienza la navegación desde Google maps. Mi pregunta era si existe algun parametro que haga esto. El codigo que tengo para que seleccione la ruta es: `https://maps.google.com/?q=ares+&mode=c&avoid=tolls`

Comment: Bienvenido, cual es l código?, revisa [ask] y edita tu pregunta agregando más información , saludos.

Comment: El código que utilizo para abrir maps es el que esta en la pregunta, solo hay que cambiar 'ares' por el destino al que quieres ir. Lo abro mediante la aplicación tasker y ya comienza la navegación. Mi duda es si a esa url se le puede añadir un parametro que haga que la aplicación de google maps de abra la navegación en modo minimizado